# Passing XML document as an parameter to Web services using C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asmx

I have to sent the XML document as an parameter to request an WebRequest using the Post method and get response. Web service implements the following method:

```
public string Register(XmlDocument register){...}
```

I'm trying doing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896213/passing-xml-document-as-an-parameter-to-web-services-in-c-sharp) , but I can't get response and I'm not sure that my code is working =(

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://ws2.sti.gov.kg/TRKService/PatentService.asmx/Register") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Encoding ex = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>");
string rawXml = doc.OuterXml;

string requestText = string.Format("register={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(rawXml, ex));

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, ex);
requestWriter.Write(requestText);            
requestWriter.Close();
```

Maybe someone has a working example?

Comment: Why not just use "Add Service Reference" to consume the service?

Comment: Hi John, when I'm trying use "Add Service Reference" I'm get following error: " The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden ( The server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator.  ). "

Comment: The easiest way is probably to contact the one providing the service and request their WSDL, so that you can build your proxy possibly using svcutil.exe

Comment: When you do the "Add Service Reference", try using the URL only up to the ".asmx". If that doesn't work, try ".asmx?wsdl". Finally, try browsing to that URL in a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**403 Error**

If your getting a 403 when trying to import the web service this may not be your fault. Try
looking at the wsdl file in your web browser. If you still get the 403 error then their is no use coding any further because you don't have permission to use that service.

**Code Syntax**

Also, in your code I it appears your not reading back the response anywhere. Your last statement writes the XML to the stream but your not reading back the response anywhere.

```
requestWriter.Write(requestText);            
requestWriter.Close();
```

**SOAP**

If the web service your are communicating with is SOAP based then your XML payload needs to conform to the SOAP standard. Your sample code above uses very basic XML, probably because it's just an example, but for it to work you will need requests with a format along the lines of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <CityName>string</CityName>
      <CountryName>string</CountryName>
    </GetWeather>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Not

```
<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>
```

Again, you've obviously only used foo for an example but this could also be the source of your problem so inspect the actual XML payload you are sending.